# CodeIgniter's session expiration

Tags: codeigniter, session

One simple question. In the documentation it says the default time before the session expires is two hours. What I would like to know is if this time is extended by the time the user has been active on the page or is it just set?

Basicaly what I would like to know is if when I stay active for two hours straight would I still loose al the session data?

I'm just worried that some of my functions won't work after the two hours even if the user is still active. Should I just log the user out after the session expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basicaly what I would like to know is if when I stay active for two hours straight would I still loose al the session data?

No, you won't.

CodeIgniter's session stores the time of the most recent activity of the user: `$session['last_activity']`.

The session will expire if there hasn't been any activity for the duration of the session expiration time since the user's last activity. It will not expire if the expiration period has passed since the session has started, but there has been more recent activity by the user.

`system/libraries/Session.php`:

```
if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
{
    $this->sess_destroy();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. This raises another question. Is there a way for me to forward the user to a controller or just a view when the session expires? The reason; I have already tried to see what happens when the session expires and it just means I loose the data. But since my logout function clears the data when I click logout after the session has already expired I get an error page..

Comment: Just check if the session exists, on every page request: ` if ($this->session->userdata('session_id')) {// session exists, do something...} else {// doesn't exist, load view/whatever...};`. You could add the same check to your logout button, to stop the error, by only destroying the session if it still exists.